# Setting the attribute values of a Model in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am learning backbone.js by following a tutorial. I tried out some code, and it appeared really strange. I first initialized a model instance with `src` being `thesource.jpg`, did a `console.log` of the model instance, then set the `src` attribute to `aaa` followed by a `console.log`.

In the javascript console, I see that for both outputs, the `src` is the same `aaa`. Shouldnt they be different?

**JS Code**

```
var Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
        src: 'placeholder.jpg',
        title: 'An image placeholder',
        coordinates: [0, 0]
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.bind("change:src", function() {
            var src = this.get("src");
            console.log('Image source updated to ' + src);
        });
        console.log('This model has been initialized!');
    },

    changeSrc: function(source) {
        this.set({src: source});
    }
});

window.myPhoto = new Photo({title: "My awesomeness",
                        src: "thesource.jpg",
                        location: "Boston",
                        tags: ['big game', 'vacation']});

console.log(myPhoto.attributes);
myPhoto.set({src:'aaaa'});
console.log(myPhoto.attributes);
```

**Console Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log objects in google chrome, their state is retrieved when you expand their properties in the console, not when you log them.

You can try to log a clone:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myPhoto.attributes)));
myPhoto.set({src:'aaaa'});
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myPhoto.attributes)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above works, but I just want to point out that Backbone has functions that do basically this already. You can use `toJSON`, which clones all attributes and returns an object.

```
console.log(myPhoto.toJSON());
myPhoto.set({src: 'aaaa'});
console.log(myPhoto.toJSON());
```

This will show a shallow copy, so it's not quite the same, but it's less to type and would still work in the case you are looking for.